# How to single sign on into gmail, yahoo mail & facebook from Spring based Web application with ldap as Authentication provider

Tags: facebook, spring, gmail, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on

We have a Spring `MVC` & `JSF` based web application which uses `Spring` security to do user Authentication using LDAP provider & after successful authentication user profile is fetched from oracle database.

Now I need to integrate facebook, gmail & yahoo mail with this application.

The expected behavior is after doing the login into this web application the user should automatically be logged in into facebook , gmail & yahoo mail as well. The user profile in the oracle database will contain the login id of gmail, facebook & yahoo mail.

The menu in the application will contain links for gmail, yahoo mail l & facebook & while user will click on those menu the corresponding site will open as logged in for that user in a iframe without asking user id & password of that website. It is good if password of gmail, yahoo mail & facebook account of the users are not needed to keep into database. Please let me know if there is any way to achieve this.

I started thinking to use `OAuth2`, but don't know whether that is right way to go forward or not. Please help me with some relevant single sign on solution to solve this.

*[Note: Web application uses Java 6, Tomcat 6, jsf as FE & hibernate as ORM & Spring MVC & Spring security framework for security]*

Answer (score 1):

Facebook, Gmail and Yahoo are themselves identity providers. Most of the documentation out there (e.g. using `OAuth`) explains how to use FB, Google or Yahoo to login into other apps.

The scenario you want to implement is the opposite: using **your own** identity provider to log in into Y!, Gmail and FB as apps (referred to RPs or SPs depending on the docs you read). In general this is not possible because they have not enabled this.

Google can (if using Google Apps) because they have enabled SAML integration. So you could potentially do it, but probably not for consumer focused gmail accounts.

Comment: We can change the identity provider from current local ldap provider to google provider using openid or something else, but will that anyway help to achieve the desired outcome.

Comment: Unfortunately not. You will solve the Google integration, but you cannot login to FB or Y! with anything but themselves.